# Containing very long text inside div

Tags: html, css, text

Okay so I have problem containing text inside div. When it's broken down with spaces, it will move to the next line but if there is 1 very long line of text, it won't move to the next line. Can someone help me with the css for this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You might try this CSS:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

or this on the containing element:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

or

```
overflow: auto;
```

Comment: Unknown property `word-wrap`

Comment: @JJP Right... `word-wrap` is CSS3 draft and already likely to be renamed to `overflow-wrap`.  Probably best not to rely on that solution.  If you NEED the text to break in a compatible way, you probably should use some JavaScript to insert spaces in any long runs it finds.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use:

```
word-break: break-all;
```