# how to auto-adjust the height of an rectangle to contain the text inside it in d3 tree

Tags: text, svg, d3.js, tree, rectangles

Hi guys i got an update in my problem........
the problem with the auto adjust of height is already solve
but another problem exist as you can see in my sample if click the node that adjust the height its child overlap it.... we can use this jsfiddle for reference http://jsfiddle.net/elviz/Ge58Q/13/

also i need to cut my text if it exceed 120 characters the other  will occupy the adjusted height of a node.....

this is how i adjust the height

```
           nodeEnter.append("rect")
          .attr("y", -barHeight / 2)
          .attr("height", function(d){
            if(d.name.length < 120){
                return barHeight;
            }else if(d.name.length > 120 ){
                return barHeight * 2;
            }
          })
          .attr("width", barWidth)
          .style("fill", color)
          .on("click", click);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't something you can do easily in SVG. [This example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321) may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you want your text formatted inside the bar. I'll go for a naive way.

You want to make the bar larger, and the amount of extra height depends on how long your string actually is.

1. Find out what your max width for a bar is, and how many characters will fit into it. Add extra height (a multiple of your original height), depending on how much text you have.
2. Use overflow-wrap, like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367752/containing-very-long-text-inside-div) to fit the text inside the div.

This is a little involved, so I hope the above gives you some ideas about how to fix your problem. I apologize in advance for not including code to solve it.