# PHP echo printing outside of my html bounds

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm making a website where users can post stories etc and they get put into the MySQL database and the front page pulls the top-rated stories from the database and fills in the HTML template I made to display.

[image: f]

So I pull the top rated post and put it inside the article tags that I've made inside my HTML. The question is when it displays it displays outside of the box. Like so

[image]

The actual display is supposed to look like this 
[image]

How do I format the PHP code, Or is there some better way to go about doing this?

```
<article class="post featured">
    <header class="major">
        <span class="date">April 25, 2017</span>
        <h2>
            <a href="#">And this is a<br />massive headline</a>
        </h2>
        <?php echo '<p>' . htmlspecialchars($row['post'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . '</p>'; ?>
    </header>
    <a href="#" class="image main"><img src="images/pic01.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    <ul class="actions special">
        <li><a href="#" class="button large">Full Story</a></li>
    </ul>
    <span class="tags badge-pill badge-primary">Otero</span>
    <span class="tags badge-pill badge-info">SCR</span>
    <span class="tags badge-pill badge-success">Class of '22'</span>
    <span class="tags badge-pill badge-danger">Male</span>
</article>
```

EDIT: Here is the HTML spot I'm talking about

Comment: Can you post some of your codes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, It`s easy to solve. First your string has only one word (because doesn´t have spaces) an second, when you have a paragraph, the tag that wrap content has an autoalignement.

Comment: Wow that's embarrassing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try adding some css rules for your parent div?

You may check this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/3367759/8186765